# Ipower max_user_connections error

Tags: mysql

So my website is a deal site that allows users to search by city for deals. I am hosting it on IPower. I have not had any problems so far except for this. Today I was on at the same time another user was and received this Mysql error `max_user_connections`. It was fleeting so this is all I remember. According to IPower: `At ipowerweb hosting, The maximum number of concurrent MySQL connections per user is 10 per user`. My searches reach into a singleton database class which opens a connection if one is not already open then performs the query. When the script is finished it closes the connection. Does this statement from IPower mean that I can only have a max of 10 users using my site at once if they are searching(quering the db) at once? It was only myself and one other user on when I received this error so I am extremely confused. The only thing I could think of was that we both performed a query at the exact same millisecond, is this possible?

P.S. I can provide the db code if necessary

**EDIT**
I ran `select @@max_connections;` and it resulted in `2000` so now I am convinced it is a`query at the same millisecond` issure but I thought Mysql could handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
set global  wait_timeout =30;
```

run it as query in your MySQL

Although you close your connections, these are not removed in MySQL
it sits idle until cleared by wait_timeout even when you set pooling to false.

So this means every all connections that are idle for 30 seconds will be removed

Comment: I'm going to contact them, I tried it and got a "must be super user error". This sounds real promising though so I'll get back soon, thanks!